# which statement to use with stored procedure with insert & select operations?

Tags: stored-procedures

well, I am wondering which statement to call on CallableStatement in order to call stored procedure with both insert and select operations, execute()/excecuteUpdate()/executeQuery(),
I'm sorta confused which one to use ? after I must do the both operations, do I have to separate the 2 operations by creating stored procedure a piece ? thank  you .

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant language/framework/database system.

Answer (score 0):

For select use ExecuteQuery()
For the rest of the crud elements use ExecuteNonquery()